# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object' with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've searched a lot and try every possible solutions but can't solve my problem.

Here is my code

```
late QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot;

Widget searchList() {
return searchSnapshot != null
    ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SearchList(
            userName: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()!['name'], //error on ['name']
            userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()!['email'], //error on ['email']
          );
        })
    : Container();
}
```

Error:

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose the type of `data` when you define `searchSnapshot`.

Try changing it to:

```dart
late QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> searchSnapshot;
```

Comment: now I'm facing `lateinitializationerror `.

Comment: This is a different problem entirely. This means that you never assign its value to `searchSnapshot`. But I can't really guess why with the code you shared.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the function data() need return a Map, not Object

Comment: how to write it?